# Review bans: 2/7/30 or 3/7/30?

Tags: support, review-suspension

According to [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222939/447378),

- 1st review ban: 2 days
- 2nd review ban: 7 days
- 3rd review ban: 30 days

But this answer to ["Review bans should escalate beyond 30 days"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287296/447378), it says:

> [image: 3 days for first review ban.]

Review ban durations have a recommended escalation.  This is very similar to account suspensions, which have a recommended escalation as below:

- [1st suspension: 7 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337009/447378)
- [2nd suspension: 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337009/447378)
- [3rd suspension: 365 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337009/447378)

But notice the first and second quotes about review ban lengths conflict with each other. One says 2/7/30, while other says 3/7/30. **Which quote is correct?**

Comment: Also note that in account suspensions, the recommended for the 3rd suspension used to be different - it was originally 7/30/120-or-deletion, but it was later changed to 7/30/365.  See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337009/447378) to learn more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that neither of the linked posts give official information about how long the first review ban is.

In the first one, the quoted duration is from a person asking a question whether these durations you list are correct. That list is *not* confirmed by the Answer, which points to information about the *automatic* durations being [set by an algorithm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174118/the-time-of-automatic-review-bans-should-be-increased-with-every-new-ban/190562#190562). It then states that moderators can set a specific duration, at their discretion, which can be any length.

The information in *that link* officially states that 2, 7 and 30 are the duration of the automatic bans.

The second post is an extraction of the screen shot in an informative post by a moderator describing a new feature for moderators. Most likely, that screen shot is a mock-up or a screen shot of a test UI where the text was later changed before the new tool was released to moderators. Notice that the user name in the screen shot is the same as that of the moderator posting that Answer, which is another indication that the image is of test-phase software. There is no *official* information in that answer that a ban duration of three days is given for the first offense.

But please keep in mind that the site owners could change the duration at any time, so the information in older posts *could* be out-dated.

Comment: So it is **2/7/30**.  I hope someone changes the screenshot on the meta link.  The suspensions are 7/30/365, they say.

Comment: Moderators can manually assign review bans of any duration we like, up to 1 year. The automated review bans increment starting from 2 days; you can find the progression described in plenty of answers on Meta to “why am I banned from reviewing?” questions.